# emacs-ESS run multiple lines of R code with one keystroke

Tags: r, emacs, rstudio, ess

Suppose I want to create this bar-plot in R:

```
barplot(table(mtcars$gear),
        xlab = "Sample x-label",
        ylab = "Sample y-label")
```

In Rstudio, I just need one keystroke (Ctrl+Enter) to generate this barplot. I can press Ctrl+Enter anywhere in lines 1, 2, 3 and it will generate this barplot.

In emacs-ESS, I have to press Ctrl+Enter three times to create the barplot (separately for the three different lines).

Is there a way to configure emacs-ESS so that just hitting Ctrl+Enter at the beginning will generate the plot?

Comment: If this code-block is isolated (blank space) from other code blocks, then `Alt-h` (`mark-paragraph`) then `Ctrl-c Ctrl-r` (`ess-eval-region`) should work. If not, then identify a region by starting at the `b` of `barplot`, then `Ctrl-Alt-f` (`forward-sexp`) twice should put you after the closing right-paren `)`, then `Ctrl-c Ctrl-r`. (Emacs often refers to `Alt` as `Meta` or just plan `M-`, so in emacs-ese those are also known as `M-h`, `C-c C-r`, and `C-M-f`, respectively.)

Comment: did you try `C-c C-c` (`ess-eval-region-or-function-and-step`)?  It's not particularly intelligent about evaluating self-contained expressions, but generally is good enough in my experience.  Coupled with the other `ess-eval-*` functions you should be able to evaluate any regions with a few keystrokes at most

Comment: Thanks to both @ r2evans and @Rorschach for your help. I was able to do this by adding this in the .emacs config file: 

`(define-key ess-mode-map (kbd "<C-return>") 'ess-eval-paragraph-and-step)`